# React, react-router-dom, axios, centralized exception handling

Tags: reactjs, typescript, axios, react-router-dom

How can I programatically navigate to my custom error page from a middle layer service class in a react application?

So I have implemented a data fetcher class, for reaching the backend. And on would like to be redirected to different pages, based on the response. And it seems to more sophisticated to do it on the UI component.

Is it possible to use redirect('... method call in service classes?
I'm on react-router-dom: 6.22.0

The Login.tsx UI component for firing the axios request:

```
  const onSubmitForm = async (formValue: any) => {
    const accessToken: string = await sendLoginRequest(formValue.email, formValue.password);
    storeToken('/', 'access_token', accessToken);
    const userInfo: UserInfo = fetchUserInfo();
    dispatch(userInfoAction.saveUserInfo(userInfo));
    navigate('/');
  };
```

The sendLoginRequest method responsible for sending the REST request to the backend, and I'd like to handle the errors here...

```
export const sendLoginRequest = async (email: string, password: string): Promise<string> => {
    return axiosApiUnauthorized.post(_getLoginEndpoint(), { 'email': email, 'password': password })
        .then(resp => {

            return resp.data.token;
        })
        .catch(err => {
            console.log('err');
            //navigate...
            redirect('/error')
        });
}
```

Also implemented an interceptor for tranforming and cathing the raw errors:

```
axiosApiUnauthorized.interceptors.response.use(
    (response: AxiosResponse) => response,
    async (error: AxiosError) => {
        const errorData: errorData = error.response?.data || {};
        const status = error.response?.status || 500;
            
        console.log('interceptor error')
        return Promise.reject({
            status,
            message: errorData.errorMsg || 'An error occurred',
            detailedMessage: errorData.detailedMsg || 'No detailed message provided',
        });
    }
);
```

I've tried using the built in redirect('/error') function and the useNavigate hook from react-router-dom.

Comment: The `redirect` utility can only be used in route loaders and actions, use the `useNavigate` hook and `navigate` function in your React components. Can you [edit] to clarify what the issue or problem is? What specific help do you need here?

Comment: My only problem was that I didn't want to add the routing logic to the UI component. And couldn't implement it in the service class.

Comment: So are you looking for something more like [navigate outside of components](/a/70000286/8690857) or [how to use navigate redirection in axios interceptor](/a/70012117/8690857)? FWIW I think it's easier to keep the navigation in the UI code initiating the side-effects, but externalizing the history/navigate for use in non-React code is possible and does work.

Comment: Okay, thanks for the info. I tried to keep ui component as small as possible. But maybe the UI can 'hold' the navigation part.

Answer (score 0):

If I'm understanding your post correctly you are wanting to conditionally navigate to an `"/error"` route if there is an error thrown during form submission.

Update the `sendLoginRequest` to return thrown exceptions and rejected Promises back to the calling code.

Don't mix `async/await` with Promise chains, either just return the Promise chain

```js
export const sendLoginRequest = (
  email: string,
  password: string
): Promise<string> => {
  return axiosApiUnauthorized.post(
    _getLoginEndpoint(),
    { email, password }
  )
    .then(response => {
      return response.data.token;
    })
    .catch(error => {
      console.log({ error });
      throw error; // <-- re-throw error for UI
    });
};
```

Or use `async/await` with a `try/catch`

```js
export const sendLoginRequest = async (
  email: string,
  password: string
): Promise<string> => {
  try {
    const { data } = await axiosApiUnauthorized.post(
      _getLoginEndpoint(),
      { email, password }
    );
    return data.token;
  } catch(err) {
    console.log('err');
    throw err; // <-- re-throw error for UI
  };
};
```

Update the `onSubmitForm` to handle the asynchronous logic in a `try/catch` and handle the thrown error/Promise rejection.

```js
const onSubmitForm = async (formValue: any) => {
  try {
    const accessToken: string = await sendLoginRequest(formValue.email, formValue.password);

    // Success, continue processing and navigate home
    storeToken('/', 'access_token', accessToken);
    const userInfo: UserInfo = fetchUserInfo();
    dispatch(userInfoAction.saveUserInfo(userInfo));
    navigate('/');
  } catch(error) {
    // Failure, navigate to error page
    navigate(
      "/error",
      { state: { error } } // <-- pass error to error page if you like
    );
  }
};
```